# Browser compatibility issues css working at Chrome while other browsers looks messy

Tags: html, css

In my site I'm setting the navagtion-bar and in Chrome its looking good, 
but at Firefox, Opera and Explorer there's misplaced elements and its really messy,
some of the Elements are moving strange at the page
How can I solve it? Do I need to start over everything?

Edit: here's my CSS code that works at Chrome

```css
.container {  background-color: #FFFFFF; box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin-top: 20px;

}

html {
    font: 1em "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-family: "Varela Round";
}

.nav-main {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
     width: 100%;

}

.nav-main > ul > li{
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-main .logo {
    height: 59px!important;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 97px;
}
.nav-main .search {
    padding-right: 70px;
}

.nav-main .netnav{
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.nav-main > ul {
    margin: 0;    
    padding: 0;
 float:right;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {
    display: inline-block; 
    line-height: 10px;
     padding-top: 18px;
}


.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;   
      color: black;
 width: 90px;
    text-decoration: none;
     border-color: black;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.nav-sub .nav-item{
     line-height: 20px;
}
.nav-content{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
 color: #000000; 
 font-family: "Varela Round";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    display: none;
    left: 1075px;
}

.nav-sub{    
    padding: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;

}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;    
}

.nav-sub ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-sub ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration:none; 
}


.nav-sub ul li:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

.nav-sub ul li:hover > .nav-item{
    color: white;
}

.nav-item:focus{
    background-color:whitesmoke;
}

.nav-item:hover ~ .nav-content{
    display: block;

}
.nav-content:hover{
    display: block;
}

.underline { box-sizing: border-box; height: auto; width: 173px; border: 1px solid #9B9B9B;}
```

Comment: I would be easier to help if you paste some screen capture, at least, and/or a piece of your css

Comment: @LuisGar I edited the question and added the full css

Comment: @O.Dror do you have css-reset styles that are loaded before your css takes effect? It's vital for cross-browser issues. Check (https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/) if you're not sure

Comment: Very difficult to give an answer... Forgetting explorer... check if Firefox version is older than your Chrome in order of its W3C update. What about Safari? Today Firefox is in it's 65 version and chrome in 72.